# Do I have a rootkit? suckit detected in /sbin/init & chkutmp errors

Tags: lubuntu

just ran chkrootkit on a recently installed 14.04 lubuntu and it came up with:

```
Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... The following suspicious files and directories were found:  
/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/vdso/.build-id
/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/vdso/.build-id

Searching for Romanian rootkit...                           nothing found
Searching for Suckit rootkit...                             Warning: /sbin/init INFECTED

Checking `chkutmp'...                                        The tty of the following user process(es) were not found
 in /var/run/utmp !
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
! root         1204 tty7   /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
chkutmp: nothing deleted
Checking `OSX_RSPLUG'...                                    not infected
```

As you can see there's some anomalies; what are those suspicious files and dirs? sickit in /sbin/init? chkutmp?
I don't get any results like that on my other machine...
So I tried rkhunter aswell, I'd post the whole log file but it's too many characters fand the post is limited to 30000

```
[12:14:00]   /usr/bin/unhide.rb                              [ Warning ]
[12:14:00] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/unhide.rb' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/unhide.rb: Ruby script, ASCII text

[12:15:19] System checks summary
[12:15:19] =====================
[12:15:19]
[12:15:19] File properties checks...
[12:15:19] Files checked: 134
[12:15:19] Suspect files: 1
[12:15:19]
[12:15:19] Rootkit checks...
[12:15:19] Rootkits checked : 291
[12:15:19] Possible rootkits: 0
[12:15:19]
[12:15:19] Applications checks...
[12:15:19] All checks skipped
[12:15:19]
[12:15:19] The system checks took: 1 minute and 38 seconds
[12:15:19]
[12:15:19] Info: End date is Mon Mar 16 12:15:19 GMT 2015
```

rkhunter doesn't seem to indicate suckit, so is that a false positive from chkrootkit? or a false negative from rkhunter? what about those other warnings, can anyone give me any insight as to what they mean? I googled a few of those anomalous results but couldn't find anything.... which is usually a bad sign.

so, do I have a rootkit and if so, how do I remove it and repair any damage done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`chkrootkit` does not do full checks for additional files with "Suckit rootkit", so this is almost certainly a false-positive if `rkhunter` does not detect the Suckit rootkit as being present on the machine in question, as `rkhunter` does do additional checks for these additional files which will be present on the system when it is infected with Suckit rootkit.

Read this for more information on `chkrootkit` detecting Suckit Rootkit's presence on the system, when in fact it is not present on the system: https://askubuntu.com/a/25179/364819

Comment: Excellent, thankyou. Seems like that's a false positive, but what about the chkutmp things then?

Comment: @JingleJoe: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)